# How do I pass in configuration settings to a docker image for local development?

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm working on a dotnet core docker container (not aspnet), I'd like to specify configuration options for it through appsettings.json. These values will eventually be filled in through environment variables in kubernetes.

However, for local development, how do we easily pass in these settings without storing them in the container?

Comment: you can mount configuration file using `-v my.config:container:/my.config` or you can pull config file from s3 or from some local server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map local volumes to docker `-v local_path:container_path`.
If you gonna use kubernetes you can use [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) as well.

Comment: (Kubernetes is pretty hard to use for the kind of local/rapid development the question hints at.)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass env variables while running the container with -e flag of the command `docker run`.

With this method, you’ll have to pass each variable in the command line. For example, `docker run -e VAR1=value1 -e VAR2=value2`

If this gets cumbersome, you can write these values to an env file and use this file like so, `docker run --env-file=filename`

For reference, you can check out the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).